# How to get the criteria of the row meet which condition?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT content_regex,content FROM mytable 
WHERE content REGEXP 'Facebook|Dropbox|Microsoft' 
AND created_date > DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 day);
```

I have search the content by using REGEXP. I would like to know is there any way to know which regexp value match with the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT content_regex,content 
, CASE WHEN content LIKE 'Facebook' THEN 'Facebook'
       WHEN content LIKE 'Dropbox' THEN 'Dropbox'
       WHEN content LIKE 'Microsoft' THEN 'Microsoft'
  END AS match
FROM mytable 
WHERE content REGEXP 'Facebook|Dropbox|Microsoft' 
AND created_date > DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 day);
```